# Usage of additional authenticated data & authentication tag for AES-GCM using BouncyCastle

Tags: java, aes, google-cloud-messaging, bouncycastle

We are planning to use `"AES/GCM/NoPadding"` in Java using BouncyCastle v1.51. Can someone shed some light on the ideal implementation / best practices with respect to the usage & generation of additional authenticated data (AAD) & authentication tag?

1. At what point should AAD be used in the encryption process?
2. As per documentation, the authentication tag is part of encrypted output. In what format is it appended to the encrypted output?
3. How is the authentication tag processed during decryption?

Following is the encryption code:

```
private static byte[] encryptGCM(byte[] plaintext,
        byte[] randomKeyBytes, byte[] randomIvBytes) throws Exception{
    SecretKey randomKey = new SecretKeySpec(randomKeyBytes, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, randomKey, new IvParameterSpec(
            randomIvBytes));    //TODO: here IvParamSpec could also be gcmP   = new GCMParameterSpec(12, keys, 32, 12); 

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, cipher);
    cipherOutputStream.write(plaintext);
    cipherOutputStream.close();
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();//this is the encrypted text
}
```

Comment: This site is not intended for code-review questions like this.  It works best when users ask specific questions about specific problems.  Please refine your question to something more specific and answerable.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this page](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/secure-login-file-transfer). The example program does not use Bouncy Castle however.

Comment: No, on the contrary I am sure the counter do repeat =) Won't all do sooner or later? In [this document](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/secure-login-file-transfer/blob/master/My%20GCM%20Research.pdf), I "argue" to the best of my ability that one IV is sufficient for 68.72 gig data. Given that my end goal is chunked file transfers (each chunk being 1 MB or something), and that one session will reasonably not surpass Long.MAX_VALUE file pieces transferred, I like to believe that the code is "quite secure".

Comment: If it was your application, would you keep track of the counter and require a new session key before the counter repeat? Thank you for your code review! Much appreciated and I feel honored =)

Comment: I think you asked a really a good question =) Anyways, [here](https://github.com/martinanderssondotcom/secure-login-file-transfer/blob/master/Library/src/main/java/martinandersson/com/library/AesGcmCipher.java#L124) is where I increment the counter and as you can see, it is a plausibility that the counter do repeat. I haven't written any code to "counter" that lol.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that the CTR IV was calculated from the given IV, your code is quite safe. As I said, long day.

Comment: omg that is so amazingly good to hear from a real pro! Not that I fully understood what you said though =)

Comment: Cannot edit my old comment. But after persisting the quote from owlstead, the new place of counter incrementation happens [here](https://github.com/martinanderssondotcom/secure-login-file-transfer/blob/master/Library/src/main/java/martinandersson/com/library/AesGcmCipher.java#L131).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer the questions in order:

1. AAD does not *have* to be used at all, the IV is already included in GCM mode encryption. For GCM you *should* always specify the AAD before any plaintext. Bouncy Castle *does handle* an update of AAD later on, but doing so requires modular exponentiation. In other words, it may significantly slow down the encryption operation.
2. The leftmost bits of the total tag are used, without any specific formatting. The bits (or, more precisely, bytes) are just appended to the ciphertext. Note that this is not specified this way for the algorithm, appending the tag is just an ad-hoc standard.
3. A full block of ciphertext is buffered and not returned as plaintext during decryption, in case it contains the tag. On `doFinal` the right amount of bytes is taken from the ciphertext and interpreted as being the tag, and the last part of the plaintext is output. Note that the buffering of ciphertext is implementation specific, but the way that `Cipher` has been defined, some buffering *has* to take place.

Comment: Note that I'm trying to see if I can rewrite the Bouncy Castle lightweight API to be able to directly return plaintext by keeping the ciphertext and tag separated. This significantly simplifies the cipher. But because the Java `Cipher` class does include the tag into the ciphertext, this won't influence the Bouncy Castle *provider*. With EAX it resulted in 30% less code, slightly faster operation and it made the cipher more online.